# Null pointer exception while exporting war file

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, war

Suddenly I can't export dynamic web project to war file using eclipse. I'm getting null pointer exception while exporting war. Here is the stack trace of exception:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingC:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software/apache-tomcat-8.0.22/webapps/ShoppingService.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getModuleParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.createFlatComponentArchiver(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.export(ComponentExportOperation.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:136)
    ... 10 more
```

Any idea about what's happen?

Comment: Perhaps you're having 2 projects using the same 3rd party libs but with differents versions

Comment: I think it is a bug. I've just solved it exporting another project successfully. Then I could export correctly.